# Not able to access my networks after deploy safe-infrastructure on localhost

Tags: gnosis-safe

How can I Run Safe-infrastructure on public IP? as my safe infrastructure running on localhost only and if i am accessing my safe wallet on public IP then i am not able to see my custom network.

[image]

kindly guide me how to make accessible safe wallets

Answer (score 0):

To make your SAFE infrastructure accessible on a public IP, you'll first need to configure your infrastructure to bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost, allowing it to listen on all network interfaces.

This change should be applied in your SAFE network's configuration files or settings.

Once this is done, ensure that your firewall and network settings allow incoming connections on the necessary ports.

Lastly, remember that exposing your SAFE infrastructure to a public IP can introduce security risks, so be sure to implement the necessary security measures such as SSL/TLS encryption, IP whitelisting, and strong authentication mechanisms.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  understood, can you also tell me where are those network configuration files are available, i have deployed whole safe infrastructure via docker compose.